# Discord.js get an array of all messages in a channel since a specific time stamp without the limit of 100

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am looking for some discord.js code that is similar to this discord.py code:

```
async for message in channel.history(after=datetime, oldest_first=True, limit=None):
```

Basically it would loop through (for or forEach) each message starting from the oldest message since a specific time. I am not sure how to bypass the 100 message limit, but if there is some way to do it, even if it is slow, that would be great.

Answer (score -3):

In Discord.js, we have the `channel.message.fetch` method:

```js
channel.messages.fetch({
  limit: Infinity,
  cache: false,
  after: datetime // The date time you want it from
}).then(messages => console.log(`Received ${messages.size} messages`)).catch(console.error);
```

[Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch)

There is no oldest_first option to use this, but you could just reverse the array and it would start from the oldest

Comment: The documentation says the "after" option is to get messages after a specific ID, not a date.